# ARG default value across multiple stages

Tags: dockerfile

How can I give a default value to `MY_ARG` if it is used across multiple stages?

```
ARG MY_ARG 

FROM something as base 
# use ARG here

FROM other as final 
# use ARG here
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright. Apparently it is as simple as doing

```
ARG MY_ARG=some-value

FROM something as base 
# use ARG here

FROM other as final 
# use ARG here
```